# get request from https with a user/password credentails

Tags: python-2.7, https

I have a https server that requires credentials(Username , password) in order to access it

Im using python2.7:

```
r = requests.get('https://icarus:10113/pc/testReport/5')
```

and Im geting the below error

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

How can I set in my code something like
`r = requests.get('https://icarus:10113/pc/testReport/5', myuser,mypassword)` to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use auth=(user/pass tuple) as following:

```
res = requests.get(url, auth=(user, passwd), headers=header, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your credentials as data tuple:

```
r = requests.get('https://icarus:10113/pc/testReport/5', data={'username':'yourusername','password':'yourpassword'})
```

Comment: Hello I tried it and its still generating SLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)